# Get NSRange from NSRegularExpression match

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsrange

I have an array which contains `NSRange` elements.

Now i can get the last range element of the array using `[resultArray lastObject]`.

When i access the last element, It returns some unknown object. (Which means Unknown class)

Now i want to cast the object into `NSRange`. How to do it?

My code is:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:paraStartRegEx options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:content options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [content length])];
NSObject *obj =  [matches lastObject];
```

How can I convert this object to `NSRange`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had read the documentation, you would have noticed that the [`matchesInString:options:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSRegularExpression/matchesInString%3aoptions%3arange%3a) method of `NSRegularExpression` returns an `NSArray` of `NSTextCheckingResult` objects, ***not*** `NSRange`s, so it's no wonder that you couldn't get them out directly.

Additionally (and you should remember this for the future, as it is an important distinction), `NSRange` is a **C `struct`**, not an Objective-C object. This means that it **cannot be directly stored in `NSArray`s or other Objective-C object containers.** `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, and other Objective-C classes that are used for storing objects **can only store objects of Objective-C types**, i.e., objects that are an instance of a `Class` and can have messages sent to them with `[object method]`.

Now to get back to your question, the array you are getting from `matchesInString:options:range:` contains `NSTextCheckingResult` objects, which contain a lot more information than just the range of the match, so you can't just cast them to an `NSRange`; you need to access the `range` property of the object to get what you want:

```
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [matches lastObject];
NSRange range = [result range];
```

Answer (score 1):

**NSRange** is a C struct.

**NSArray** does not hold C types, only objects.

**NSRegularExpression** returns a match **NSArray** that contains objects of **NSTextCheckingResult** type.

**NSTextCheckingResult** has a range property that returns the range of a match.